# How to color bars based on a separate pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I need to plot a barchat and to apply a color according to the "Attribute" column of my dataframe

[image]

x axis = Shares
y axis = Price

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(df['Share'],df['Price'], align='center')
ax.set_xlabel('Shares')
ax.set_ylabel('Price')
ax.set_title('Bar Chart & Colors')
plt.show()
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There are two easy ways to plot the bars with separate colors for `'Attribute'`

  1. Transform the dataframe with [`.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and then plot with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) and specify `kind='barh'` for a horizontal bar plot

     - The index will be the x-axis if using `kind='bar'`, and will be the y-axis if using `kind='barh'`
     - The columns of the transformed dataframe will each be plotted with a separate color.
     - `pandas` uses `matplotlib` as the default plotting backend.
  2. Use [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) with `hue='Attribute'` and `orient='h'`. This option works with the dataframe in a long format, as shown in the OP.

     - `seaborn` is a high-level API for `matplotlib`
- Tested with `pandas 1.3.0`, `seaborn 0.11.1`, and `matplotlib 3.4.2`

### Imports and DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# test dataframe
data = {'Price': [110, 105, 119, 102, 111, 117, 110, 110], 'Share': [110, -50, 22, 79, 29, -2, 130, 140], 'Attribute': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   Price  Share Attribute
0    110    110         A
1    105    -50         B
2    119     22         C
3    102     79         D
4    111     29         A
5    117     -2         B
6    110    130         B
7    110    140         C
```

### `pandas.DataFrame.plot`

```py
# transform the dataframe with .pivot
dfp = df.pivot(index='Price', columns='Attribute', values='Share')

Attribute      A      B      C     D
Price                               
102          NaN    NaN    NaN  79.0
105          NaN  -50.0    NaN   NaN
110        110.0  130.0  140.0   NaN
111         29.0    NaN    NaN   NaN
117          NaN   -2.0    NaN   NaN
119          NaN    NaN   22.0   NaN

# plot
ax = dfp.plot(kind='barh', title='Bar Chart of Colors', figsize=(6, 4))
ax.set(xlabel='Shares')
ax.legend(title='Attribute', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left')
ax.grid(axis='x')
```

[image]

- with `stacked=True`

```py
ax = dfp.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, title='Bar Chart of Colors', figsize=(6, 4))
```

[image]

### `seaborn.barplot`

- Note the order of the y-axis values are reversed compared to the previous plot

```py
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='Share', y='Price', hue='Attribute', orient='h')
ax.set(xlabel='Shares', title='Bar Chart of Colors')
ax.legend(title='Attribute', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left')
ax.grid(axis='x')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very useful ! Is it possible to aggregate at price level and to the color split ? For example if I have 1 price , 3 shares level and 3 attributes I would like to create one bar instead of creating 3 bars (what's done)

Comment: @MinatoDBO You can use `stacked=True` with `df.plot`. However, I don't recommend stacking bar, because they are more difficult to compare values with.

Comment: Ok many thanks , last question for me please ! Is it possible to add a horizontal line ? I tried to do ax.hlines(y=117, xmin=-50, xmax=125, linewidth=2, color='r') but it didnt work

Comment: @MinatoDBO Bar plot isn't actually indexed by the number shown. They addressed position (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3, ...). So you can do `ax.hlines(y=4, xmin=-50, xmax=125, linewidth=2, color='r')`. If the answer is beneficial, in addition to accepting it, you may also upvote the answer.